# Escape Regex special characters in jq

Tags: json, regex, string, jq

I want to do search and replace in a larger `jq` program.
The problem is that `search` may contain special characters that are interpreted as regex functionality, which I dont want. Special characters should be treated like normal characters.

So what I need is a regex format escaping function, similar to `@uri`, `@html` or `@sh`.
How can I escape *all* special characters that have meaning in regular expressions (brackets, ., ?, *, + etc.) in the search string so that they are not interpreted as regex syntax?

```sh
TEXT='Hello $ spaceman Spiff'
SEARCH='Hello $'   # does not work, because '$' is interpreted as regex special character
REPLACE='Ola '
echo "$TEXT" | \
jq -rR --arg search "$SEARCH" --arg replace "$REPLACE" 'gsub($search; $replace; "g")'
```

In the original program, 'search' and 'replace' are defined in an external file (passed here by parameter) and the replacement takes place as part of a larger processing of text data coming from another external source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def deregex:
  reduce ("\\\\", "\\*", "\\^", "\\?", "\\+", "\\.", "\\!", "\\{", "\\}", "\\[", "\\]", "\\$", "\\|", "\\(", "\\)" ) as $c 
    (.; gsub( $c; $c));
```

Example:

```
"^.*$",
 "/*",
 "*/"
| [., deregex]
```

produces:

```
["^.*$","\\^\\.\\*\\$"]
["/*","/\\*"]
["*/","\\*/"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to be sure a list is complete if Oniguruma doesn't provide the escape function, but for example the R implementation' escape function includes normal parens which I don't see in deregex. https://github.com/jonclayden/ore/blob/dd32adec7d6d6dcfa681e2a07a15097b12bdf08e/src/escape.c#L41

Comment: @lossleader - Parens added.

Answer (score 2):

The limits of working without functions that use regexes may be peferable to the risks of missing any regex syntax, for example with `split/1`:

```
TEXT='Hello $ spaceman Spiff'
SEARCH='Hello $'   # does not work, because '$' is interpreted as regex special character
REPLACE='Ola '
echo "$TEXT" | \
    jq -rR --arg search "$SEARCH" --arg replace "$REPLACE" 'split($search)|join($replace)'
```

Comment: this is a clever idea that gives me a smile ... thanks

Comment: @jpseng sure, if you want to go with regexes don't forget replace variable might also look like capture group references, etc.

Comment: Escaping parens is sufficient to avoid potential difficulties with capture groups.